# UNIX: Using a regex that matches either single or double quotes with grep

Tags: shell, grep

I have a string say

```
string="MYSTRING"
```

Now I want to grep for any occurrence of `"MYSTRING"`  (with double quotes) such that there must be parentheses at starting, basically I want to search, in which places `"MYSTRING"` is used as function's parameter. So,

```
foo( "MYSTRING"    //postive
foo("MYSTRING"      //positive
foo('MYSTRING'      //positive
foo( 'MYSTRING'      //positive
var a = "MYSTRING"  //negative
```

I used:

```
string="MYSTRING"
regexstring="[(]*\"$string\""
grep -e "$regexString" <<'EOF'
foo( "MYSTRING"    //postive
foo("MYSTRING"      //positive
foo('MYSTRING'      //positive
foo( 'MYSTRING'      //positive
var a = "MYSTRING"  //negative
EOF
```

Ideally, all the items with "positive" next to them and none of the items with "negative" will match. What needs to change to make that happen?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I corrected my question statement. Can you please take a look now and remove downvote.

Comment: `regexstring = "[(]*\"$string\""` remains invalid syntax which will not actually run an assignment. `grep -rn $regexString` remains incorrect in a way that http://shellcheck.net/ will report on. We want one question to a question -- if something that has other bugs that stop code execution from getting to the problem that's purportedly being showcased, that's suboptimal.

Comment: Which is to say -- in an ideal world, we could directly copy-and-paste your code from your question and see your current output. (A description of *how* that current output differs from intended output is also a desired component).

Comment: I tested `regexstring = "[(]\"$string\""` . It's valid. I need help in 2 things:
First:  How I can ensure that there can be space between `(` and start of `$string`
Second: How can I have single or double quotes around.

Please help.

Comment: No, it's not valid. `regexstring = "[(]\"$string\""` runs `regexstring` as a command, with `=` as its first parameter; spaces aren't allowed around the `=` in an assignment in shell. If you were testing **the exact code** given in your question to actually work, you'd know this.

Comment: aaaahh.. yes, let me correct I am manually writing things. Please consider without spaces around `=`

Comment: Which shell? Can we assume code that will only be run with bash, not POSIX sh?

Comment: It's bash and csh only. Not POSIX

Comment: I can't help you with csh, only bash. csh is an utterly incompatible shell, and needs its own question separately tagged.

Comment: Ok, Please help as per the bash shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to do this is to use the ksh extension (adopted by bash) `$''` to provide a literal string that can include backticks.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
string=MYSTRING
regexstring=$'[(][[:space:]]*[\'"]'"$string"$'[\'"]'
grep -e "$regexstring" "$@"
```

---

Breaking down this assignment:

```
$'[(][[:space:]]*[\'"]'
```

...is a string literal which evaluates to the following:

```
[(][[:space:]]*['"]
```

...thus, it matches a single `(`, followed by zero or more spaces, followed by either `'` or `"`.

The second part of it is a double-quoted expansion, `"$string"`; this should be fairly straight on its face.

The final part is `$'[\'"']'`; just as in the first part, the `$''` string-literal syntax is used to generate a string that can contain both `'` and `"` as contents.

---

By the way -- in POSIX sh, this might instead look like:

```
regexstring='[(][[:space:]]*['"'"'"]'"$string""['"'"]'
```

There, we're using single-quoted strings to hold literal double quotes, and double-quoted strings to hold literal single quotes.